# java как динамически менять кол-во активных потоков?

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня есть ExecutorService serviceOne. И я когда создаю объект thread pool, я объявляю кол-во потоков внутри моего executor:

```
serviceOne = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberActiveThreads);
```

В работе программа есть момент когда надо изменить кол-во этих потоков, ув/уменьшить их.

---

Не нашел внутри этого класса нужной ф-ции. Подскажите как можно сделать так, чтобы получилось в процессе работы программы менять число активных потоков в пуле потоков. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: ну вам название `FixedThreadPool` не подсказывает разве, что это за объект? Ищите другой Executor для такой задачи.

Comment: Боюсь что придется написать свою реализацию

Comment: @tym32167, я нашел ThreadPoolExecutor, он может помочь в моей ситуации?

Comment: У меня нет ответа на ваш вопрос, но есть вот ссылка, что легко гуглится -  [Dynamic Thread Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32527532/312041)

Comment: А что за задача такая, которая требует изменения количества потоков в пуле?

Comment: Обработка разных файлов. Изменение кол-ва потоков с учетом возможностей железа ПК. Если используем более слабое железо выставляем нужное кол-во потоков, мощное - ожидаем, что больше потоков увеличат производительность.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из возможных вариантов решения данной проблемы может быть использование не FixedThreadPool, а ThreadPoolExecutor. Для этого необходимо:

```
//Для хранения задач
BlockingQueue<Runnable> threadPool = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
//Наш пул потоков
ThreadPoolExecutor serviceOne = new ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, 
           int maximumPoolSize, 
           long keepAliveTime, 
           TimeUnit unit, 
           BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, 
           ThreadFactory threadFactory,
           RejectedExecutionHandler handler)
```

---

Что использовал я:

```
threadPool = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
serviceOne = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 10, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, threadPool);
```

Далее в нужный момент вызываем ф-цию и передаем нужное нам значение numThread:

```
//Выставляем новое значение activeThread
serviceOne.setCorePoolSize(numThread);
```